# panic: runtime error: cgo argument has Go pointer to Go pointer

Tags: golang

Программа падает с ошибкой: `panic: runtime error: cgo argument has Go pointer to Go pointer`. Падение происходит в последней строчке:

```golang
func CreateListener(channel, query string, startpos EVT_SUBSCRIBE_FLAGS, watcher *LogEventCallbackWrapper) (ListenerHandle, error) {
    cChan := C.CString("Application")
    cQuery := C.CString("*")
    listenerHandle := C.CreateListener(cChan, cQuery, C.int(startpos), C.PVOID(watcher))
    // …
}
```

Описание типа `LogEventCallbackWrapper`:

```golang
type LogEventCallbackWrapper struct {
    callback          LogEventCallback
    subscribedChannel string
}
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос определение типа `LogEventCallbackWrapper`.

Comment: Добавил описание

Answer (score 0):

В вашей структуре `LogEventCallbackWrapper` у вас как минимум один указатель (поле `subscribedChannel` является строкой, которая в свою очередь является «жирным указателем» [англ. «fat pointer»]), а тип `LogEventCallback` скорее всего является указателем на функцию.

[Документация](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/) инструмента `cgo` напрямую запрещает передачу подобных объектов в код на си, так как это может вызвать ошибочное поведение сборщика мусора:

> Go is a garbage collected language, and the garbage collector needs to know the location of every pointer to Go memory. Because of this, there are restrictions on passing pointers between Go and C.
>
> (…)
>
> Go code may pass a Go pointer to C *provided the Go memory to which it points does not contain any Go pointers.* The C code must preserve this property: it must not store any Go pointers in Go memory, even temporarily. When passing a pointer to a field in a struct, the Go memory in question is the memory occupied by the field, not the entire struct. When passing a pointer to an element in an array or slice, the Go memory in question is the entire array or the entire backing array of the slice.

(Выделение добавлено.)